# What's the medical ankle bracelet used for?

Tags: short-films

In the short film [*911* by Lady Gaga](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58hoktsqk_Q), an accident is portrayed from the perspective of an unconscious victim in a near-death/dream scenario. In the end, the victim awakes and we learn what's actually happening and we can see how the real world ties into the dream world we have witnessed before.

An ankle bracelet is quite heavily featured in the early part of the dream sequence, then echoed in the final denouement/reality scene at the end.

[image] [image]

There is also a pre-echo of her pose in the ambulance in the final sequence, also showing this bracelet.

[image]

During the final reality scene, the paramedic applies something to the victim's ankle before starting resuscitation. Near the end of the film (around 4:04), we see that the victim has a black ankle bracelet attached at this exact spot.

[image]

My first thought was that this was just done to stabilize the ankle, but you would not prioritize this and start resuscitation right away instead, before caring for the ankle. Therefore, I assume that there is more to it and the bracelet serves another purpose and not just stabilization.

Searching for ankle bracelet and resuscitation didn't bring up anything useful. Can anyone shed some light on the purpose of this device and what this is called?

Comment: For those wondering whether Music Videos are on-topic as they are not very commonly asked.  I've reviewed the meta and while it is not conclusive, the overall impression is that if they are short films with imagery or story (as opposed to music videos that are simply performance of the music) then they can be considered on-topic like other short movies.

Comment: I don't think 'reanimation' is the word you're looking for. It would be 'resuscitation' except she's already conscious & in no need of resuscitation.

Comment: @Tetsujin - You are right! I'm not a native speaker and it seems like I used this term incorrectly my entire life. Thanks for the clarification, I'll change it in my question right away.

Comment: Welcome!! Reanimation is more… voodoo, or Frankenstein's monster, beloved of horror directors since hand-cranked black & white silent movies;)

Comment: I'm not worried about the "short film" being on topic (although it's actually a music video) BUT I'm pretty sure that identifying a minor object in the video IS off-topic as trivia if nothing else.

Comment: That said, it's explicitly stated in the "short film" that it's a **tourniquet**

Comment: @Paulie_D - I can see your point; but it clearly echoes & reinforces why they were so keen to show us the ankle bracelet in the opening desert scene, so would fall under 'aids understanding' if we're being magnanimous. I've added some more of this precursor to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my niece, an actual patch you up in the back of the ambulance fully-qualified [actually over-qualified] Paramedic
You can tell she found it somewhat amusingly mis-applied…

> it appears to be a CAT tourniquet. Which is meant to be used in a catastrophic bleed to stop someone bleeding to death following trauma. Two problems with this application in this case 1) it is meant to be only applied on a single bone so, in this case if the severe bleed is in the lower leg, this should be applied to the upper leg over the femur and 2) this is clearly not a severe bleed and certainly isn’t life threatening and this medical device is not actually needed